# ProxyPass with trailing slash returns 404

Tags: apache, tomcat7, proxypass, apache2.4

Consider the following configuration :

```
ProxyPass /myapp  http://localhost:8080/myapp
ProxyPassReverse /myapp  http://localhost:8080/myapp
```

Now requests that are made to `http://www.example.com/myapp/foo/bar` will be routed to my app with the expected results to the browser. However a request made to `http://www.example.com/myapp/foo/bar/` will return a 404.

I observe the same results when I update the `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` directives with the trailing forward slash.

I know that my Controller in my Spring app is set up to handle this URL pattern as calls made to `http://localhost:8080/myapp/foo/bar/` work as expected.

I am using Apache 2.4 and Tomcat7. I have the following modules loaded:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule proxy_html_module modules/mod_proxy_html.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

Comment: What does the error log say?

Comment: There is no error in either my apache log or tomcat log.
The apache access log just states that it returned a 404.

Comment: ever found a solution for this?

Comment: @Brian I have the same problem, do you have a solution?